# How to output Excel.workbook content into existing Excel file from C# application?

Tags: c#, excel, output

I have a macro-enabled Excel file "D:\MyTests\ExcelTests\template.xlsm" with no data in it, only the VBA code, and my C# code needs to output a workbook data over there. Normally I output workbook data like this:

```
        Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Add();
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet2 = workbook.Sheets[2];

        // populate worksheets with some data
        DataTable2Worksheet(tableMain, worksheet, verSize);
        DataTable2Worksheet(tableExtra, worksheet2, 0);

        string fileName = @"D:\MyTests\ExcelTests\newFile";

        if (File.Exists(fileName ))
        {
            File.Delete(fileName );
        }

        workbook.SaveAs(fileName);
        workbook.Close();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
```

but this creates a new file (which cannot be macros enabled programmatically). If I want to output the workbook to existing file

```
        string existingFile = @"D:\MyTests\ExcelTests\template.xlsm"
```

the method

```
        workbook.SaveAs(existingFile );
```

won't work. So, what should I do instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Save the file specifically in [`xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017(v=office.15).aspx):

```
string existingFile = @"D:\MyTests\ExcelTests\template.xlsm"
workbook.SaveAs(existingFile, 52);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it just replaces already existing file with the new one with the same name -- and VBA macro is now gone.

Comment: @Evgraph - This is the supported way to accomplish what you are asking. I would assume that macros are available in your `existingFile` at the time of save, and if so this should work.